# analytics.js has a delay before starts loading?

Tags: google-analytics, seo, delay, code-snippets

I've found this issue and can't find any similar posts or solutions to it.

Here is the screenshot of timeline waterfall:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzUhK.jpg]
[Link to picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzUhK.jpg)

As you can see there is pretty big gap before analytics code starts loading, about 200ms, which is not good whatsoever. Is there a solution to make it start loading when it's supposed to start loading?

P.S. Issue seems to persist in all browsers. screenshot is taken in firefox, since its the most easy-to-see.

P.P.S. here are illustrations of my question:

[image]
Shouldn't it supposed to be like this?:
[image]

P.P.P.S. here is screenshot of chrome: smaller gap, but still exists.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Browsers execute Javascript code as soon as they reach a `<script>` tag when parsing a page.
By looking at the website inspected in your screen capture (www.a1sp.com) I see that your Google Analytics script is located near the bottom of the page. 
So, your browser will execute this code only when reaching the `<script>` tag after everything located above.
You can move your code at the beginning of the page if you want to launch it earlier.
[According to Google](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080?hl=en), you can safely place the tracking code before the closing `</head>` tag.

Comment: I'm not sure if my question is understood correctly. The question is why there is a gap between end of receiving request to fontawesome font and beginning of loading analitycs.js , not why script loads close to the end of the page.

Comment: I have no such gap on my side in Chrome 39. With Firefox it happens sometimes but not always. I saw that one image is taking a long time to load 'xconcrete-company-houston.jpg', maybe the browser takes a lot of resources to render this image and thus defer the loading of the script...

Comment: Yes, Chrome does work faster, that's for sure. Although, there is still a gap, even if it's significantly smaller: